# Does Apache Aurora have an API?

Tags: mesos, apache-aurora

Is the command-line client the only way to submit jobs? Is there a REST or language-specific API?

Comment: https://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/hooks/ implies that it does, but you'll have to read the source, since it's not part of their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great and frequently asked question.

Apache Aurora does not currently have a first-class scheduler HTTP/JSON API, but it is being planned ([AURORA-987](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AURORA-987)) and an API is one of several ideas that has discussed as a potential projects that may be worked on during a June Aurora community hackathon.

An [open call for ideas and feedback](http://markmail.org/message/j5v3at3erbo7vipc) was sent out to the project mailing list a few months ago, and if you're interested in being part of that discussion I'd suggest joining #aurora on irc.freenode.net, and the project mailing list by emailing dev-subscribe@aurora.apache.org.